# Efficent way of internet calls in android

Tags: android, azure, azure-mobile-services

My current android app is azure mobile app where a user can book any service.I need to show the status of his order like booked,pending completed in a fragment.I am right now doing it by calling api but everytime fragments gets created it calls api even if no data is changed.What is the possible and efficient solution of doing this.

Comment: There is nothing bad in caling api, only you need to check that you don't call api if data is available already in activity fields. You can use swipeRefreshLayout to let user refresh data whenever he want.

Comment: If you dont want call api you can save your data in database and load data from database instead of calling api, whenever data is changed from server, then send notification to all devices. Devices will invalidate old data and fetch new data from api again.

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario, the orders data are stored in your server-side database. Though you could store the retrieved order data into the local storage (e.g. SQLite,etc) on your mobile client, in order to retrieve the latest order status, you must explicitly call your mobile app backend for retrieving the latest order info and update your local order status. At this point, you could try to decrease the response data size returned by your backend via specifying minimum fields in your request. Details you could follow the `.select()` [field selection clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library#selection).

Moreover, you could also follow Khemraj's suggestion about the notification approach, but the push notification may needs user interaction.